# MotionEvents triggering no matter what in Android

Tags: java, android, android-touch-event

I have this code for my MotionEvents in Android:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    int action = event.getActionMasked();

    switch (action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mGameview.moveUp(30);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mGameview.moveDown(30);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

However, instead of these things only triggering when I drag my finger up/down, they both happen simultaneously no matter what I do in the app, for example when I tap, drag left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get action by:

```
int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
```

Comment: sorry it took so late for me to get around doing this, but it still triggers regardless with this addition. do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: maybe your action form gameview triggers touches?